# Temp integers not resetting

Tags: java

I am creating a histogram using another class to help display it, but that is not important to my question. Let me start by showing my code below

```
public class DisplayHistogram {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int temp = 0;
    int holder = 0;
    int average;
    Random rand = new Random();
    Histogram x = new Histogram(1, 20);

    for(int i = 0; i<=10000; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<=3; j++)
        {
            temp = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
            holder = holder + temp;
        }
        average = Math.round(holder / 3);
        x.submit(average);
    }
    System.out.println(x.toString());
 }

 }
```

the problem I am having is I set the histogram to have a min of 1 and max of 20. I am generating three random integers and finding the average of the 3 and submitting it to the histogram 10,000 times. However, after the first loop of 10000, the "holder" variable doesn't reset back to 0 causing my program trying to submit a value outside of the max, and creating an error. I have attempted to set holder to 0 at the end of every loop by doing

```
 x.submit(average);
 holder = 0;
 temp = 0;
```

However that does not help.

I have tried some of your suggestions making my code look like

```
import java.util.*;
public class DisplayHistogram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Random rand = new Random();
Histogram x = new Histogram(1, 20);

for(int i = 0; i<=10000; i++)
{
    int temp = 0;
    int holder = 0;
    int average = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<=3; j++)
    {
        temp = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
        holder = holder + temp;
    }
    average = Math.round(holder / 3);
    x.submit(average);
}
System.out.println(x.toString());
}

}
```

However it still returns this error

```
 Exception in thread "main" HistogramOutOfBoundsException: 
 *******
 Submitted value 22 is outside range [1,20] of Histogram.
 *******

at Histogram.submit(Histogram.java:31)
at DisplayHistogram.main(DisplayHistogram.java:19)
```

Comment: Where do you reset the `holder` variable?

Comment: I tried resetting the holder variable below my submit statement, I showed it in my second bit of code but didn't display it in my first.

Comment: In fact, you should declare your temp, holder, and average variables inside the first gor loop as they serve no purpose after the for loops are executed.

Comment: Also, you mentioned you wanted the average of 3 numbers , currently its 4 numbers not 3.

Comment: ^^ This is my problem. I'm a complete idiot and was looping three times instead of four.

Answer (score 0):

Write your loops like this:

```
   for(int i = 0; i<=10000; i++)
    {
        holder = 0; // add this line
        for(int j = 0; j<=3; j++)
        {
            temp = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
            holder = holder + temp;
        }
        average = Math.round(holder / 3);
        x.submit(average);
    }
    System.out.println(x.toString());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Was looping four times instead of three. For loop should've looked like

```
 for(int i=0; i<=2; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

Pay attention to details.

### The answer you want

Unlike the other answer,
don't just initialize the holder variable every loop.
Instead, minimize the scope of the holder variable to the loop.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int average;
    Random rand = new Random();
    Histogram x = new Histogram(1, 20);

    for (final int trialCount = 0; trialCount <= 10000; ++trialCount)
    {
        int holder = 0;

        for (final int sampleCount = 0; sampleCount <= 3; ++sampleCount)
        {
            int temp = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
            holder += temp;
        }

        average = Math.round(holder / 3);
        x.submit(average);
    }
    System.out.println(x.toString());
 }
```